# How to effectively and efficiently group items into paired buckets (if they exist)

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

I'm creating an automated ranked matching system where two candidates optionally rank one another and the system finds the optimal matching pair based on both candidates' rankings.

More specifically, the "poster" creates a post and an "applicant" applies, this application creates two ranking entries to allow both parties to rank one another separately.

I start by fetching these rankings from the database producing an array of data structure:

```
rankings ==> [ {postID, rankerID, rankeeID, ranking}, ...]
```

I then bucket these rankings by postID (with Lodash's groupBy):

```js
_.groupBy(rankings, rank => rank.postID);
```

And this produces bucketed rankings by postID, as an example:

```
{
  postID_1: [
    { postID: 'postID_1', rankerID: 'applicantA', rankeeID: 'posterA', ranking: 1 },
    { postID: 'postID_1', rankerID: 'posterA', rankeeID: 'applicantA', ranking: 4 }
  ],
  postID_2: [
    { postID: 'postID_2', rankerID: 'posterB', rankeeID: 'applicantA', ranking: 3 },
    { postID: 'postID_2', rankerID: 'applicantA', rankeeID: 'posterB', ranking: 5 },
    { postID: 'postID_2', rankerID: 'applicantB', rankeeID: 'posterB', ranking: 1 }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Notice how there is not always a complete pairing showing rankings for poster ==> applicant and applicant ==> poster.

Ultimately I want to determine who the best poster-applicant match candidate is based on specific criteria and their rankings, so I need to determine how to transform the above structure to buckets of pairs, as a desired outcome:

```
{
  postID_1: [
    [
      { rankerID: 'applicantA', rankeeID: 'posterA', ... },
      { rankerID: 'posterA', rankeeID: 'applicantA', ... }
    ]
  ],
  postID_2: [
    [
      { rankerID: 'applicantA', rankeeID: 'posterB', ... },
      { rankerID: 'posterB', rankeeID: 'applicantA', ... }
    ],
    [
      { rankerID: 'applicantB', rankeeID: 'posterB', ... }
    ]
  ],
  ...
}
```

I'm just having trouble formulating the data transformations while bucketing the (possibly) existing pairings with functional programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go! We use `Array.reduce` and check if the "other half of the pair" exist already and complete that if it does. Otherwise we add a new pair.

```js
const data = {  postID_1: [    {      postID: "postID_1",      rankerID: "applicantA",      rankeeID: "posterA",      ranking: 1    },    {      postID: "postID_1",      rankerID: "posterA",      rankeeID: "applicantA",      ranking: 4    }  ],  postID_2: [    {      postID: "postID_2",      rankerID: "posterB",      rankeeID: "applicantA",      ranking: 3    },    {      postID: "postID_2",      rankerID: "applicantA",      rankeeID: "posterB",      ranking: 5    },    {      postID: "postID_2",      rankerID: "applicantB",      rankeeID: "posterB",      ranking: 1    }  ]};

const result = Object.entries(data).reduce(
  (accResult, [key, postData]) => ({
    ...accResult,
    [key]: postData.reduce((acc, val) => {
      const secondHalf = acc.find(
        ([{ rankerID, rankeeID }]) =>
          rankerID === val.rankeeID && rankeeID === val.rankerID
      );
      if (secondHalf) {
        secondHalf.push(val);
        return acc;
      } else {
        return acc.concat([[val]]);
      }
    }, [])
  }),
  {}
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you! I had started down the path of a reducer after creating this post and hit a wall, and this is spot on.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help